# Getting the first line of a running child process output

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to save the generated URL from a Serveo command to a variable.
My code works, but once I visit the generated link, some output gets added to the stdout and then my variable changes.

```
let ls = cp.spawn("ssh", ["-R", "80:localhost:4200", "serveo.net"]);
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  ls.stdout.on("data", async function(data) {
    shellinabox.Localtunnel.URL = await data
      .toString()
      .split(" ")[3]
      .replace("\n", "");
    resolve(shellinabox);
  });
});
```

At first, my code gives me the link 
ex: https://justanexample.serveo.net
Then once I go to the link, my variable changes to "to" which is the 4th word in the new stdout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find out how to always get the first line of a stdout but I ended up not over complicating the problem by checking if the variable is empty before checking the stdout

```
let serveo = cp.spawn("ssh", ["-R", "80:localhost:4200", "serveo.net"]);
shellinabox.Serveo.PID = serveo.pid;
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  serveo.stdout.on("data", async function(data) {
    if (shellinabox.Serveo.URL == null) {
      shellinabox.Serveo.URL = await data
        .toString()
        .split(" ")[4]
        .replace(/[\u001b\u009b][[()#;?]*(?:[0-9]{1,4}(?:;[0-9]{0,4})*)?[0-9A-ORZcf-nqry=><]/g, "")
        .replace("\r", "")
        .replace("\n", "");
      resolve(shellinabox);
    }
  });
});
```